# Integrate stripe checkout form with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I need to integrate the stripe checkout form in my angularjs site, i have tried everything from github repositories to different plugins and nothing works. I like the look of the stripe checkout form so i don't want to create my own. I am extremely new to angularjs.

I have tried angular-payments, stripe-checkout-form and a couple other git repositories

```
<md-content layout="row" layout-align="center">
  <md-card flex layout-align="center center">
    <div style="width: 100%; padding: 1em">
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <md-button ui-sref="account" class="md-primary md-fab md-fab-top-left">
          <md-tooltip md-direction="top">My Account</md-tooltip>
          <md-icon style="color:white;font:bold;" md-menu-origin class="material-icons">account_box</md-icon>
          <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
        </md-button>
        <h2>List of devices</h2>
        <md-list>
          <md-list-item class="secondary-button-padding">
            <span ng-repeat="title in headers" ng-style="{width:100/4+'%'}">{{title}}</span>
          </md-list-item>
          <div ng-repeat="device in devices | orderBy: 'ChargeDate'">
            <md-divider></md-divider>
            <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
              <div ng-style="{width:100/4+'%'}">{{ device.Name}}</div>
              <div ng-style="{width:100/4+'%'}">{{ device.ChargeDate }}</div>
              <div ng-style="{width:100/4+'%'}">
                <md-select name="plans" ng-model="selectedPlan" ng-model-options="{trackBy: selectedPlan}" aria-label="Select Plan" 
                          ng-change="selectedPlanChanged(device, selectedPlan)" md-selected-text="resetSelectedPlan(device, selectedPlan)" ng-disabled="planDisabled">
                            <md-option value="{{plan.rowID}}" ng-repeat="plan in plans">{{ plan.name }}</md-option>
                        </md-select>
              </div>
              <div ng-style="{width:100/4+'%'}">
                <md-switch class="md-primary" layout-align="center center" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="device.Active" ng-change="switch(device)"
                           ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'">
                </md-switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </md-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-card>
</md-content>
<div>
{{ message1 }}
</div>
<div>
{{ message2 }}
</div>
<md-button flex-xs="50" flex="100" ng-click="showConfirmationWindow($event)" ng-disabled="!hasUnsavedPlanChange" class="md-raised md-accent" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
  <div>
    Update payment plan
  </div>
</md-button>
<md-button ng-if="$isDev" flex-xs="50" flex="100" ng-click="showAdd($event)" class="md-raised md-accent" layout="row" layout-align="start center">
  <div>
    <md-icon>add_box</md-icon>
    Add device. DEVELOPER FUNCTION.
  </div>
</md-button>
```

I want the payment for to pop up when i click a button and it communicate with stripe

Comment: Have you tried this angular component for Stripe? https://github.com/westphalen/ng-stripe-checkout

Comment: Thats for angular 2+, i'm using angularjs. I really don't know how to achieve this

Comment: I am looking for same thing. The stripe v3 checkout looks great and I am not able to find any solution for this